# PhantomJS + CasperJS from Ruby - Reuse Code?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, casperjs

I am calling CasperJS from the backend of my Ruby on Rails application using `Open3.popen3` to make a command line call. The filename (in my case CoffeeScript) is the first argument followed by options.

Many of my coffee files do similar tasks. I see examples of of how to reuse code with modules, but I think that's a NodeJS only thing.

Any suggestions how I might reuse common code in my situation?  I'm really getting horribly un-DRY.

**UPDATE:**

[hexid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457584/1816580) is correct. What I was missing when I tried it before is that you need the rooted file path, not relative the current file path:

```
my_module = require('/rooted/path/to/the/file.coffee')
```

Comment: is there any advantage of doing it that way over using Poltergeist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS has support for [CommonJS' require](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1).

You won't, however, be able to require NodeJS modules because PhantomJS doesn't run on NodeJS, but instead on a version of Webkit that is included in QT.